# In Django form, is there an equivalent for initial={'authuser':request.user} in formset_factory?

Tags: django

[Short version of the question] 
So I have been using normal forms so far. In this case, I used 
`form = myForm(initial={'authuser':request.user})` code to distinguish the user from others and let him/her fill his/her own form. (I had `authuser` as foreign key to User model, obviously).
But then I tried to use `inlineformset_factory` this time, but can't figure out how to do what I've done with normal forms. Any advice on this? Thank you very much.

[Longer version of the question] 
So I have the following model.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionNumber = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionNumber

class Answer(models.Model):
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    questionTitle = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    dateAnswered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionTitle
```

What I'm trying to do is let users answer to each question. But here I'm trying to use `inlineformset_factory`, since I want to let user add their answers as time goes by. So I believe I'll have to use `Question` as the parent model and `Answer` as the child model. 
 However the problem is, how do I let each user fill in his/her own answer form? In normal forms, I used `form = myForm(initial={'authuser':request.user})` to get the `request.user`'s own form. But I can't figure out it in `formset_factory` 

I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks. 
+++
So here's my views.py. I've set the `initial= ...` part as instructed on the docoumentation, but it seems like it doesn't work. No matter which account I log into, I get the same formset with all the previous data saved.

```
def index(request): 
    today = datetime.today()

    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerForm, extra=1)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(initial=[
        {
            'authuser':request.user
            }
        ])
        if request.method == "POST":
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            
            return redirect('index')


    return render(request, 'formset/index.html', {'formset':formset})
```

And my template.

```
<body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col col-10">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col col-12">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{formset.as_p}}
                        <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: [Yes there is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset)

Comment: Note that if you set `initial={'authuser':request.user}`, then the user can submit the form with a different `authuser` value. It's safer to exclude `authuser`, and set the value when you save the form.

Comment: @Alasdair Oh you mean I have to save ```authuser``` when saving the instance?

Comment: @Alasdair I tried it, but I got this error: ```'list' object has no attribute 'authuser'```. What do you think could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Save with `commit=False` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)), set the `authuser`, and then save the instance. In the formset case, you'll have to loop through the instances ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset)), you can't set `formset.authuser`.

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you very much for the advice. However it seems like it doesn't work. I've updated my question--added the ```views.py``` below. Could you please go over it and see what I've done wrong? Again, I appreciate it very much.